# Using Apache SystemUtils Java

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-commons-lang

I am trying to use the Apache Java library SystemUtils to determine the operating system being used. Here is a link:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

I am using netbeans to create my application. I can not figure out how to use the library.  I have tried importing it but it does not seem to be installed.  I have tried finding a download and adding that but I am unable to find one.

Could someone please give me some advice on how to get this library working using netbeans?

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Download](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi) the commons-lang-2.5-bin.zip
2. Extract it, and find the `commons-lang-2.5.jar`
3. Add that jar to the classpath of your project by:

   > right click your project > Properties > Libraries > Add Jar/Folder

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for Netbeans 6.7. It should not be too different in other versions.

1. Select your project
2. Open Run > Set Project Configuration > Customize...
3. In Categories, select Libraries
4. In the Compile tab, click on Add JAR/Folder...
5. Select the commons-lang JAR.

If you are using Maven, just include the commons-lang dependency in the `<dependencies>` section of your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```